# Implementing tabslideout with Drupal 7

Tags: php, jquery, tabs, slide

I am trying to add a jquery plugin tabslideout to my Drupal 7 site (theme 
It's been explained many times, I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300258/adding-tabslideout-javascript-to-drupal-7) for Drupal 7, but it does not work on my site.
I am an absolute rookie, and I can't get my head around php, it seems I can't get the function to work.

First, I've added the script in the .info file.

Next, I added the following code to my page--front.tpl.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
    tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'sites/all/themes/temp3/images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image               //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: false                      //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
});
});
</script>
```

And further down:

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
<a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users.html">Content</a>
<h3>Contact me</h3>
<p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.
</p>
<p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
```

And, I added CSS

```
.slide-out-div {
padding: 20px;
width: 250px;
background: #ccc;
border: 1px solid #29216d;
}
```

Only the div shows on the page...

I also found this code, unfortunately it doesn't work as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.tabslideout = {
    attach: function() {
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut {
    tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'sites/all/modules/tabslideout/images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: true                     //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
};.next().hide();
};
 };
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

I presume there must be something totally different I haven't thought of before because I simply don't know, and this makes an expert laugh out loud ;)
The same page contains a 'flexslider' element.

///////////// Thanks a ton for any comment/ suggestion! //////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.tabslideout = {
    attach: function() {
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut {
tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
pathToTabImage: 'sites/all/modules/tabslideout/images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
fixedPosition: true                     //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
};.next().hide();
};
};
  })(jQuery);

</script>
```

With

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut {
    tabHandle: '.handle',                     //class of the element that will become your tab
    pathToTabImage: 'sites/all/modules/tabslideout/images/contact_tab.gif', //path to the image for the tab //Optionally can be set using css
    imageHeight: '122px',                     //height of tab image           //Optionally can be set using css
    imageWidth: '40px',                       //width of tab image            //Optionally can be set using css
    tabLocation: 'left',                      //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
    speed: 300,                               //speed of animation
    action: 'click',                          //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
    topPos: '200px',                          //position from the top/ use if tabLocation is left or right
    leftPos: '20px',                          //position from left/ use if tabLocation is bottom or top
    fixedPosition: true                     //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
};
};

</script>
```

as the website describes it

and if this does not works try to remove the 
    .next().hide();

Cheers.

Comment: Hi there - thanks  a lot - I've tried both options but unfortunately it didn't work. I've no idea why, but it only loads the text in the div, no js... Do you know how the code of the function would be to load the jquery script directly from within the page.tpl.php...?